# Creating an HTML collapse accordion with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion, yet I only managed to get the first collapsible button to work properly while the other collapsible buttons not only don't work - they also don't show up at all .

When I delete the css for the "content" variable , all the content shows properly, yet the "day" buttons are unclickable (dont do what theyre supposed to)

I have tried a few codes and not knowing JS very well, I copied the JS code from a W3Schools page (while of course making the components myself) and thence I struggle to understand how they work and how I can fix it.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("daytitle");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;


    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}



/*
I ALSO TRIED:

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
} */





/*for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  } );
}

*/
```

```css
.daytitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #c2c2d6;
  border-color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
}

.daytitle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="daytitle"> Day <i class="arrow"></i></button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="Attraction1" class="attraction">
    <div class="atr_image"><img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="atr_container">
      <div class="atr_name"><a>Atr Name </a></div>
      <div class="atr_region">Atr Region</div>
      <div class="atr_desc">
        <p>Atr Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="atr_time_container">
        <div class="atr_time">
          <p>3 Hours</p>
        </div>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <div class="atr_hours">
          <p>10:00-13:00</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="button1" id="R1 " onclick="Remove(this.closest('.attraction'))">Remove Attraction</button>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

I also tried using the Bootstrap library and deleting the js code, but this doesnt work either. Unlike the first option, in which it only shows the first button and the first component - here it shows all the components open - yet no "day" button seems to be clickable.

```
<button class = "daytitle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="<?php echo "#.content.$l_daynumber" ?>" > <?php echo "Day ". $l_daynumber; ?><i class="arrow"></i></button>

<div id = "<?php echo "content.$l_daynumber" ?>" class = "content">
```

Full code with php:

```
for($u = 0; $u < count($arr);$u++){
    
    
    
    $hour = intval($arr[$u]["Time"]);
    
    $time = $time + $hour;
    
    if($l_daynumber < $maxdays)
    if($time > 8|| $first_time == 0|| $early_atrtype === 1){
        
        $l_daynumber++;
        $first_time = 1;
        $time = 0;
        $this_hour = 10;
        $early_atrtype = 0;
        $atr_in_day = 0;
            ?>
        <html>



<button class = "daytitle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="<?php echo "#.content.$l_daynumber" ?>" > <?php echo "Day ". $l_daynumber; ?><i class="arrow"></i></button>

<div id = "<?php echo "content.$l_daynumber" ?>" class = "content">

</html>





        <?php
        
        
    }
    
    
    $name = $arr[$u]["Name"];
        //$region = $arr[$u]["Region"];
    $desc1 = $arr[$u]["Desc"];
    $hours = $hour . " Hours";
    
    
    $nexthour = $this_hour + $hour;
    $actual= "$this_hour : 00 - $nexthour: 00";

    
    if(similar_text($arr[$u]["Atrtype"],"157") > 0 && $nexthour > 19){
        
        $early_atrtype = 1;
        
    }
        $this_hour = $nexthour;
    
    if($this_hour > 24){
        $this_hour = $this_hour - 24;
    }
    
    $numofatr++;
    
    $atr_in_day++;

        ?>      

    <html>
    
    
<div id = "<?php echo "Attraction.R.$numofatr" ; ?>" class = "attraction">

<div class = "atr_image"><img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt=""></div>

<div class= "atr_container">


<div class = "atr_name"><a><?php  echo $name; ?> </a></div>
<div  class = "atr_region"><p><?php   echo $region;?> </p> </div>
<div class = "atr_desc"><p><?php  echo $desc1; ?></p></div>

<div class = "atr_time_container">

<div class = "atr_time"><p><?php  echo $hours; ?> </p></div>
<span class= "dot" ></span>
<div class = "atr_hours"><p><?php echo $actual; ?></p></div>

</div>


<button class="button1" id = "<?php echo "R. $numofatr"?> " onclick = "Remove(this.closest('.attraction'))">Remove Attraction</button>

<script>



 
       
function Remove(elem){
    //var Attraction = document.getElementById("Attraction"+elem);
   // Attraction.remove();
   
  // document.getElementById(Attraction).parentNode.removeChild( document.getElementById(Attraction))

    elem. remove();

}




    


</script>

</div>
</div>

<?php
if($time > 8){
    
    ?>
    </div>
    

    <?php

}



?>


<style>


.content {


}

</style>



<script>





/*for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  } );
}

*/

/*var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("daytitle");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

*/


/*for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
} */
</script>

    
    
    </html>
```

Note 1: I am using PHP values to construct the components that make up the "content" class, but didn't include the PHP code here.

Note 2: I am still new to the community and to web development and I don't know jQuery or advanced CSS at all and only know basic JS. If there are easier solutions involving them I will try to implement them anyway.

Note 3: the time variable works fine and I don't think the problem lies here

I would appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Please paste in the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean how the html looks like in the web page? could you explain yourself (as i said im new)

Comment: The code you posted still has all the PHP variables. View source on your web page, and copy that section and edit your question to replace your HTML section. Do the same for the button markup as well.

Comment: I understood what you meant. I think I  edited it, but the id names are defined by php and generated dynamically , so I cant remove that part

Comment: only names and innerhtmls use php commands in my code, it shouldnt be the cause of the problem

Comment: I'm not asking you to remove the PHP code at the end. I want you to view the source on your web page, and copy the HTML that is output by your PHP. `<?php echo "#.content.$l_daynumber" ?>` we don't know what that outputs. Or this `<?php echo "Attraction.R.$numofatr" ; ?>` - that's what will help us help you.

Comment: @disinfor I edited, and also added the full code with the php in a seperate area

Comment: Again, you keep adding your PHP, when we need to see the rendered HTML. Your Javascript is based on the HTML output, not the PHP.

Comment: i fixed the html part though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("daytitle");
var i;
var x = document.getElementById("content1");

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function collapse() {
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.daytitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #c2c2d6;
  border-color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
}

.daytitle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="daytitle"> Day <i class="arrow"></i></button>
    <div id="content1" class="content">
      <div id="Attraction1" class="attraction">
        <div class="atr_image"><img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="atr_container">
          <div class="atr_name"><a>Atr Name </a></div>
          <div class="atr_region">Atr Region</div>
          <div class="atr_desc">
            <p>Atr Description</p>
          </div>
          <div class="atr_time_container">
            <div class="atr_time">
              <p>3 Hours</p>
            </div>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <div class="atr_hours">
              <p>10:00-13:00</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="button1" id="R1" onclick="collapse()">Remove Attraction</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

but the only problem with this answer is that after you collapse the content, to bring it back up you will have to double click the day button, other than that it should work.

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is there may be more than one "content "and their ids are generated with php .

Answer (score 0):

This accordion doesn´t use any coded javascript.

The idea is that the state of each content container is controled by the status of the input. The input may be either a checkbox, which allows multiple selections, or a radio which will allow only one selection at a time. The inputs are grouped by the name property.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tab grey">
        <input id="tab-0" type="checkbox" name="tabs">  <!-- set the input type to radio if you want only one accordion open at a time -->
        <label for="tab-0">
            <!-- The text for the accordion title --> 
        </label>
        <div class="tab-content grey">
            <!-- Your content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- repeat how many tabs as you want -->
</div>
```

The function of what I deem most relevant will be commented in the code bellow

#### CSS

```
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  /* this makes the input invisible */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
label { 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 0 0 0.3em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.tab-content {
  /* default status invisible (height: 0) */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #1abc9c;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

/* :checked */
input:checked ~ .tab-content {
/* if the input next to the tab is checked, increase height */
  max-height: 25em;
}
/* Icon - here are some nifty stuff... makes the de sign at the end of the label rotate if the content is visible or not */
label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .35s;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "+";
}
input[type=radio] + label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

This construct with a little css tinkering can become a tabbed layout.